# Python statsmodel ARIMA prediction difference between versions

Tags: python, version, prediction, statsmodels, arima

I have a training set of passengers:

```
train['Passengers']

Month
1949-01-01    112
1949-02-01    118
1949-03-01    132
1949-04-01    129
1949-05-01    121
...
1959-08-01    559
1959-09-01    463
1959-10-01    407
1959-11-01    362
1959-12-01    405
Freq: MS, Name: Passengers, Length: 132, dtype: int64
```

Now using statsmodel I want to implement ARIMA(8,1,1).

However, statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA seems to predict different values than the deprecated version statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.

statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
arima = ARIMA(train['Passengers'], order=(8,1,1))
arima_result = arima.fit()
arima_result.predict(start=train.index[1], end=train.index[-1])

Month
1949-02-01    112.034073
1949-03-01    119.751782
1949-04-01    135.651835
1949-05-01    124.246608
1949-06-01    116.279857
...   
1959-08-01    542.722017
1959-09-01    481.743123
1959-10-01    413.868022
1959-11-01    354.078873
1959-12-01    355.815461
Freq: MS, Name: predicted_mean, Length: 131, dtype: float64
```

statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
arima = ARIMA(train['Passengers'], order=(8,1,1))
arima_result = arima.fit()
arima_result.predict(start=train.index[1], end=train.index[-1])

Month
1949-02-01     2.532206
1949-03-01     3.585345
1949-04-01     6.018756
1949-05-01    -2.077600
1949-06-01    -1.577707
...   
1959-08-01   -10.896945
1959-09-01   -86.790586
1959-10-01   -49.189211
1959-11-01   -50.916200
1959-12-01    -3.487137
Freq: MS, Length: 131, dtype: float64
```

How is it possible? And how would I get back predictions of the deprecated version using the new version?

Comment: The treatment of constants differs between the old, now deprecated version.  Take a look at the parameters to see the difference. With d=1 you probably need `trend="t"` in the new ARIMA code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using arima_result.predict(..., trend='t') within the new ARIMA code does not seem to work. What else would you suggest?

Comment: You specify the trend when you construct the model. This then allows the parameters associate with trend terms to be estimated, and then used in forecasting.